# how to pass a UI ImageView from one view controller to another? swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimage

I am trying to pass this UI Image View from one view controller to another on the same storyboard. I have already passed a UI TextField to a UI Label and UI Button. Now I need to do it with a UI Image View.

Here are my two view controllers.

```
import UIKit

class PhotoShareViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentTextView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var thatTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var thisTextField: UITextField!
    var presenter: PhotoShareModuleInterface!
    var image: UIImage!


    @IBAction func thisUploadPhoto(_ sender: Any) {

        if thisTextField.text != "" && thatTextField.text != ""
        {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
        }
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        var photoShareLabelViewController = segue.destination as! PhotoShareLabelViewController


        photoShareLabelViewController.thisString = thisTextField.text!

        photoShareLabelViewController.thatString = thatTextField.text!

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        imageView.image = image
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func didTapCancel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        presenter.cancel()
        presenter.pop()
    }

 /*   @IBAction func didTapDone(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        guard let message = thatTextField.text, !message.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        guard let messageOne = thisTextField.text, !messageOne.isEmpty else {
            return
        }



        presenter.finish(with: image, content:message)
        presenter.dismiss()
    }
}
 */
}

extension PhotoShareViewController: PhotoShareViewInterface {

    var controller: UIViewController? {
        return self
    }
}
```

if someone could tell me how to send the image from one view controller into another that would be awesome!

Comment: what you mean by passing in "I have already passed a UI TextField to a UI Label and UI Button."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't show `PhotoShareLabelViewController`, but presumably it has:

```
var thisString: String?
```

Add

```
var thisImage: UIImage?
```

And then pass it along the same way as `thisString`

```
photoShareLabelViewController.thisImage = imageView.image
```

And pick it up in the `viewDidLoad` of `PhotoShareLabelViewController` (which is probably where you pick up `thisString`).  Something like:

```
self.imageView.image = self.thisImage
```

But, using whatever variable name you are using.

In short, just copy what you are doing for `thisString`, but use a `UIImage` as the type instead of `String`.

NOTE: You are not passing a UIImageView from one VC to another (that is impossible).  You are passing the image from an imageview from one VC to another.